# How to write log message in QGIS's script algorithms GUI tab?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, log

I want to write some log in the log tab of processing algorithm User Interface.

I tried this :

```
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog

QgsMessageLog.logMessage("test")
```

but when I launch the script "test" is not logged.

[image]

How to write a log in the processing User Interface ?

the [processing guide log's chapter](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/processing/log.html) doesn't tell much about writing a log in this tab.

If i use :

```
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog
QgsMessageLog.logMessage("test", tag="Processing", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)
```

the log result is wrote under the console log panel called "Processing", but not in the processing GUI log tab.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with global variable `progress`. [see the user manual, processing chapter](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#communicating-with-the-user)

```
progress.setText('Youpi')
```

Will print 'Youpi' in the processing log.

It supports html formatting:

```
progress.setText('<b>Youpi</b>')
```

to print in **bold**...

progress come also with `setPercentage()` methods to control the progress bar

Comment: that's exactly what I am looking for ! thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately I will get an error: "NameError: name 'progress' is not defined" Do I have to import a special module?

Comment: @Vaiaro I wrote this answer long time ago and the api of processing has change a lot... You probably need to check the doc for qgis3 to see the new way of doing that.

Answer (score 9):

For QGIS 3.x you can use the `pushInfo()` method on a `feedback` object:

```
feedback.pushInfo('This is a log message')
```

See the [scripts section](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#communicating-with-the-user) of the user's manual for other relevant methods.

Comment: how do you create or acquire the feedback object in the first place? with `QgsProcessingFeedback.pushInfo('a message')` I get the error _"TypeError: QgsProcessingFeedback.pushInfo(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsProcessingFeedback'"_

Comment: have you tried the following `feedback.pushInfo('This is a log message')` ?