# Writing log message in QGIS's script algorithms GUI tab for PyQGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I want to write some log in the log tab of processing algorithm User Interface like [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259954/how-to-write-log-message-in-qgiss-script-algorithms-gui-tab) but for QGIS 3 (PyQGIS 3).

It seems that "progress.setText('Youpi')" does not work anymore.

What's the good way ?

Comment: Try `QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Youpi')`

Comment: Then check this answer:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310787/getting-log-message-from-qgis-processing-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
feedback.setProgressText('Youpi')
```

work properly.